# Error in joined table: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm capturing inventory data from an inventory snapshot table. I've written a view for the snapshot table which works fine, but then when I join that to another table I am getting the error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function." and am unclear as to what's causing that

The following code is the view I've built to summarize the snapshot table

```
Select 
qty_ordered W_QtyOrdered, 
qty_shipped WQty_Shipped, 
on_hand_1 WOnHand, 
item_no, 

CASE 
WHEN Item_no IS NULL THEN 'Z00000'
ELSE LEFT(item_no, LEN(item_no) - 4) 
END AS ItemNo

from westrock.inventory where inventory._modified >= (select 
max(_modified) from westrock.inventory)
```

this query, as I mentioned, runs fine.

The view below though, is what causes the error. As you can see, I'm doing a left join to an existing inventory table to get a global inventory view.

```
select location_id, full_name, locationName, item_id, displayname, 
   LOCATION_ON_HAND_COUNT, LOCATION_ON_ORDER_COUNT, 
   LOCATION_QUANTITYBACKORDERED, 
   LOCATION_AVAILABLE_COUNT, LOCATION_REORDER_POINT 
   , ir.W_QtyOrdered, ir.WQty_Shipped, ir.WOnHand, 
   ir.item_no, ir.ItemNo
    from dw_item_location
   left join westrock.InventoryReport IR on 
      dw_item_location.znumber = IR.ItemNo
  where location_id = 2 or location_id = 3
```

Comment: Maybe you have `item_no` shorter than 4 characters in your table? `LEFT(item_no, LEN(item_no) - 4) ` expects an `item_no` that is longer than 4 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle `item_no` that has fewer than 4 characters

```
Select 
  qty_ordered W_QtyOrdered, 
  qty_shipped WQty_Shipped, 
  on_hand_1 WOnHand, 
  item_no, 

  CASE 
    WHEN Item_no IS NULL THEN 'Z00000'
    WHEN LEN(item_no) <= 4 THEN item_no
    ELSE LEFT(item_no, LEN(item_no) - 4) 
  END AS ItemNo
from westrock.inventory 
where inventory._modified >= (select max(_modified) from westrock.inventory)
```

Answer (score 1):

What is hard to get?  If the length is less than 4, then you'll get an error.  So, change the logic to:

```
(CASE WHEN Item_no IS NULL THEN 'Z00000'
      WHEN LEN(item_no) <= 4 THEN item_no
      ELSE LEFT(item_no, LEN(item_no) - 4) 
 END) AS ItemNo
```

Comment: The length of that field is never less than 4 unless it’s null which I thought is accounted for properly. Will try this

Comment: Are you sure?  Have you done a simple `SELECT Item_no FROM westrock.inventory WHERE Item_no IS NOT NULL AND LEN(Item_no) < 4`?  The error you received would only be related to the length of `Item_no`.